# javascript mongoose get value of arrayFilter array index and use as a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update a field using the arrayfilter variable this is what I have done so far.

```
var items='green shirt'

Model.update({
    id: 7c59453a6194a90217defc70
},{
    {$set:{
        'arrayname.$[firstArray].field1':'my new name',
        'arrayname.$[firstArray].field2':'myusername'
        'arrayname.$[firstArray].field3':[items+[arrayname.$[firstArray].field4]]
    },
    arrayFilters:[{"firstArray._id":7c59453a6194a90217defc70}],
    new:true, safe:false}},
    function(err, update){
        if(err){}
        else{}
    })
```

By using the arrayFilter I would be able to get the specific array which I want to work on. 
Now my logic is, the arrayFilter would get the index of the specific item and make it 
available within the $set expression. 
How can I get the arrayIndex and use it as a variable for the value. as indicated in field3 above

```
'arrayname.$[firstArray].field3':[items+[**arrayname.$[firstArray].field4**]]
This produced an error arrayname is undefined
```

Some other which I have tried

```
1.  'arrayname.$[firstArray].field3':[items+[`**arrayname.$[firstArray].field4**`]]
It was inserted into the data as a string
```

Some might say the best is to use a find and save method inside the update, but I am looking at
a way of reducing the call to the server.

This would do (as I believe) make the program more efficient